# how can stop stream after start stream with ffmpeg php?

Tags: html, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm attempting to run the following command in PHP (on Ubuntu):

it is start button
    start

```
 <?php
 if (exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi >/dev/null 2>/dev/null&")) 
  { echo "Success"; }
  else { echo "No good"; }
```

so after start how i can kill-stop this with -php code

Any ideas on this  be working for stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ffmpeg process will be running in the background I presume.  You could use a `killall ffmpeg` command (assuming only one is ever running) or if you could somehow determine the PID then send it a signal like `kill -15 <PID>` GL!

Comment: The PID can be acquired with `pgrep ffmpeg`.

Comment: `exec` runs commands "just like ssh does" FWIW, you're even already using it :)